# How do I load the app/models/** from a Gem in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I wrote some business logic in a app without rails loaded, just active record and using a test database so I can have tests run blazingly fast.

Now that I'm done with that, I'm having trouble getting my models and stuff loaded up.

My gem directory looks somewhat like this:

```
- app
  - models
    - user.rb
- features
- spec
- biz-logic.gemspec
```

However when I  require this gem though a private git repo

And fire up rails c in my rails app

User is uninitialized and doing require 'biz-logic' does nothing.

So how do I get this working properly? Do I need to require rails in my gem?

Comment: Those paths inside your gem don't look very standard.  Rubygems usually expects to be loading files from the lib directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a lib/biz-logic.rb file

Inside that file you would have:

require 'user'

and you will have to move user.rb inside gem/lib/user.rb